# Rasterize (Vector to raster) ERROR 6

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I'm trying to convert a polygon to raster. This error pops up:

> ERROR 6: At least one of -3d, -burn or -a required.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you select an attribute field (which is the `-a` parameter) from your polygon layer before trying to run the tool?

Comment: i did not.. what does the -a parameter describe?

Comment: The parameters are described here: [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html). The `-a` parameter is defined as: _"Identifies an attribute field on the features to be used for a burn-in value. The value will be burned into all output bands."_. Essentially, the tool requires a value from the polygon layer to be _burned_ into the raster. The `-3d` parameter is currently only for points and lines so you don't need to use that. The `-burn` parameter allows you to use a single value instead of values in a field.

Comment: ah okay I tried that and generated a attribute field with zeros only and one "1". That worked

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameters for the `gdal_rasterize` are described in the following link:

http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html

The parameters in your error are described as follows from the link:

- `-a attribute_name`:

  > Identifies an attribute field on the features to be used for a burn-in value. The value will be burned into all output bands.
- `-burn value`:

  > A fixed value to burn into a band for all objects. A list of -burn options can be supplied, one per band being written to.
- `-3d`:

  > Indicates that a burn value should be extracted from the "Z" values of the feature. As of now, only points and lines are drawn in 3D.

Essentially, the tool requires a value from the polygon layer to be *burned* into the raster. The `-a` parameter allows you to use values from an attribute field; `-burn` parameter allows you to use a single value instead of values in a field; `-3d` parameter is currently only for points and lines so you can ignore this one.