# Making black and clear raster image from polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, rasterization

I have made a polygon in QGIS (I just drew a polygon), but how do I make this into a raster image?

I want the raster image to be black (where the polygon was) and clear where the polygon wasn't.

I have tried using rasterize with a variety of options, but I always end up with an empty raster.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is the same problem as here: [Rasterize (Vector to raster) ERROR 6](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240028/rasterize-vector-to-raster-error-6)

In the options dialogue in the rasterize-tool, set burn-in value to 1 (to get black value for the extent of your polygon) and select a resolution (like units for output-raster in pixels and horizontal and vertical resolution set to 100 - or more if you wand a smoother image, or less if you want to have a rough output is OK). See screeshot for details (in german, but should become clear when you compare with your interface):
[image]